# I would like to copy data from 1 row to another in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba

I am trying to solve the following issue in excel:  I am working in two sheets, Sheet 1 and Sheet 2. There is a column of data in sheet 1 (say from A5 to A20). I need every row from that column to be pasted/ referenced to every nth row in Column A, Sheet2. Please, What is the best way to do this?

Example of what I am trying to achieve:

```
A(n) from sheet 1 -> A(x) sheet 2<br>
A(n+1) from sheet 1 -> A(x+7)5 sheet 2 <br>
A(n+2) from sheet 1 -> A(x+14) sheet 2<br>
A(n+b) from shee 1 -> A (x+b*7) sheet 2<br>
etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this macro replaced AnotherSheet with the real name of it:

```
Sub MyMacro()  

' Part 1 - first move the range to another sheet
Range("A5:A20").Select      
Selection.Copy      
Sheets("**AnotherSheet**").Select      
ActiveSheet.Paste      

' Part 2 - move the cell to right place
Dim r As Range

For Each r In Selection
  r.Cut
  r.Offset(r.Row * 7).Select
  Selection.Insert
Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure if you read the description or not,but what you are suggesting is a simple copy-paste. I want the values from the rows from sheet A to be pasted to different row locations in sheet B.

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA something like this works -

```
 =IF(MOD(ROW(A1),3)<>1,"",INDEX(Sheet1!A:A,MOD(ROW(A1),3)+INT(ROW(A1)/3)))
```

Replace the `3` with the `nth` row you want and drag it down & across on Sheet2, or whatever your sheet names are.